# Broadcom WMP54G firmware missing

Tags: 10.10, wireless, broadcom

I am using a PC, running Windows 7 as main OS and Ubuntu 10.10 as secondary OS.
I have loaded the Ubuntu as an 'app' through Wubi installer.
I have booted into Ubuntu and found that I am unable to connect to the internet, getting a message that I have 'Missing Firmware' for my wireless device.

I have been looking up this subject for quite a while. I have looked into the 'Additional Drivers' but the driver does not come up there. The only drivers I see are ones for my Nvidia graphics card.

Please Help,
Thankyou.

Comment: I solved it by removing and installing the drivers again.

Answer (score 2):

OP solved:

> I solved it by removing and installing the drivers again.